# Why is my SFML sprite not showing texture?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to create a game. I have a class GameObjects that many classes will inherit from. The class GameObject has a draw method that takes the window address to the display. Why does the sprite show up without the texture when displayed like this?

[image: Game Running]

[image: EmptySquare.png]

This is the texture, more of a placeholder. I was able to load it in other files directly creating the sprite and drawing it.
Here is my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"

int main()
{
    //window setup
    Game game;

    //Initialize game
    game.start();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my Game.h

```
#pragma once

#include "GameObject.h"

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Game
{
private:
    //window variables
    int w_width;
    int w_height;

    sf::RenderWindow window;

    sf::Event ev;

    bool isRunning;

    std::vector<GameObject> o_vector;

    
    void initVariables();
    void initWindow();
    void initObjects();
    void drawObjects();
public:
    void start();
    void run();
    void input();
    void update();
    void render();
};
```

And Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "GameObject.h"

void Game::start()
{
    this->initVariables();
    this->initWindow();
    this->initObjects();
    this->run();
}

//Initializations
void Game::initVariables()
{
    isRunning = true;
    
    //window variables
    w_width = 1280;
    w_height = 720;
}

void Game::drawObjects()
{
    for (int o_count = 0; o_count < o_vector.size(); o_count++)
    {
        o_vector.at(o_count).draw(window);
    }

}

void Game::initWindow()
{
    //window creation
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(w_width, w_height), "The Dungeon Crawler", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Resize);
}

void Game::initObjects()
{
    GameObject baseObject;
    o_vector.push_back(baseObject);

}

void Game::run()
{
    while (isRunning)
    {
        input();
        update();
        render();
    }
}

void Game::input()
{
    while (window.pollEvent(ev))
    {
        switch (ev.type)
        {
        case sf::Event::Closed:
            window.close();
            break;
        case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
            switch (ev.key.code)
            {
            case sf::Keyboard::Escape:
                window.close();
                break;
            case sf::Keyboard::A:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void Game::update()
{
}

void Game::render()
{
    window.clear(sf::Color(0, 0, 128));

    drawObjects();

    window.display();
}
```

Here is GameObject.h

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>


class GameObject
{
private:
    std::string name;

    std::vector<int> o_position;
    std::vector<int> o_size;

    std::string t_path;
    sf::Sprite o_sprite;
    sf::Texture o_texture;

    void initVariables();
public:
    //Constructors & Destructors
    GameObject();
    ~GameObject();


    //Getters
    std::vector<int> getPos();
    std::vector<int> getSize();

    sf::Sprite getSprite();

    //Setters
    void setPos(std::vector<int>pos_in);
    void setSize(std::vector<int> size_in);

    //Graphics
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow &displayWindow);
};
```

And GameObject.cpp

```
#include "GameObject.h"

GameObject::GameObject()
{
    initVariables();
}

GameObject::~GameObject()
{

}

void GameObject::initVariables()
{
    o_position = { 0,0 };
    o_size = { 64,64 };

    t_path = "Resources/EmptySquare.png";

    if (!o_texture.loadFromFile(t_path))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    o_sprite.setTexture(o_texture);
}

std::vector<int> GameObject::getPos()
{
    return o_position;
}

std::vector<int> GameObject::getSize()
{
    return o_size;
}

sf::Sprite GameObject::getSprite()
{
    return o_sprite;
}

void GameObject::setPos(std::vector<int> pos_in)
{
    o_position = pos_in;
}

void GameObject::setSize(std::vector<int> size_in)
{
    o_size = size_in;
}

void GameObject::draw(sf::RenderWindow &displayWindow)
{
    displayWindow.draw(o_sprite);
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Just to be sure, the texture has been loaded correctly?

Comment: Yes, the texture is properly loaded

Answer (score 2):

the problem is this line in `Game::initObjects()`

```
GameObject baseObject;
o_vector.push_back(baseObject);
```

- you creata a copy of `GameObject`.
- so it will make a copy of `o_sprite`.
- the `o_sprite` copies the texture pointer.
- after this function ends, the texture pointer is no longer valid.

`sf::Sprite` has the member `const Texture* m_texture;` and when calling `sf::Sprite::setTexture(const Texture& texture)` this member `m_texture` will in fact point to the texture. That texture will be destructed after `initObjects()` ends, and your element at position 0 will have a `o_sprite.m_texture` that points to this destructed object. [SFML/Sprite.hpp](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/include/SFML/Graphics/Sprite.hpp)

---

you could define the correct `operator=(GameObject)` that implements the correct sprite copy - or in this case simply say:

```
void Game::initObjects()
{
    o_vector.resize(1);
}
```

`resize` will call the constructor of `GameObject` and you will have no copies and therefore dangling pointers.

[image: sprite now loaded in the program]

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be for you to allocate game object on the heap and store a pointer to it in the vector. This way you will avoid the cost of copying.

To make these changes, declare `baseObject` as private member of `Game` class and in `initObjects` method allocate it on the heap.

```cpp
class Game
{
private:
    GameObject *baseObject;
    std::vector<GameObject *> o_vector;
};
```

```cpp
void Game::initObjects()
{
    baseObject = new GameObject;
    o_vector.push_back(baseObject);
}
```

```cpp
void Game::drawObjects()
{
    for (int o_count = 0; o_count < o_vector.size(); o_count++)
    {
        o_vector.at(o_count)->draw(window); // use -> operator to call draw
    }
}
```

PS: Instead of raw pointer, you can also use C++11 smart pointer.